# How to access Service in $httpProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I created a config service to provide environment specific configurations. I'm using the `$httpProvider` to intercept and extend the request url with a API Base Url but how do i access the config service from within `$httpProvider`?

I've read about the `$injector` but i did not understand how to use it to solve my problem.

```
// pseudo code, not working
app.service('Config', function() {

    // configuration property object

    return {
        get: function (property) {
            return property
        }
    } 
});

app.config(function ($httpProvider, Config) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {

                // extend config.url to add a base url to the request
                if (config.url.indexOf('api') !== -1) {
                    config.url = Config.get('root') + config.url;
                }

                return config || $q.when(config);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: service instance isn't available in config function, you can only inject constants

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you know any workarrounds?

Comment: It depends on how you want to implement the Config service. If it's just a simple object with key-value pairs, you should define it as a constant, i.e. `app.constant('Config', {...})`

Comment: Thanks. Please add your comment as answer so i'm able to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider, Config) {
```

to:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
```

and this line:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
```

to:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, Config) {
```

This works because the function you push to the interceptors is essentially an angular service that can be defined like this:

```
angular.app('app', [])
  .service('HttpInterceptor', function($q, Config) {
     return {
       request: function() {
         // Do whatever
       }
     };
  });
```

Which can be passed in the `config` function like this:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');
```

As long as your HttpInterceptor service does not call on `$http` or anything that depends on `$http` (... like `$resource`), you'll be fine. @Ye Liu was right in his comment that services are not allowed to be injected into the config function. However, services can be injected into other services.